# No of ways of choosing $a,b$, $1 \le a, b, \le 1000$, such that $ab = 2^6 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^4$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, factoring

I am trying to work out the number of ways of choosing $a$ and $b$, $1 \le a, b \le 1000$, such that $ab = 2^6 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^4$.

Attempt 1) Times indices of the numbers together, since $6$ ways of choosing powers of two, $2$ for $3$, and $4$ for $5$, giving $6\cdot 2\cdot 4=48$

Attempt 2) writing out all possible ways that can factor $ab$.

Questions:
1) What are quick by hand methods for this type of problem?
2) How if any is this related to "$n$ choose $r$" formula for combinations?

Comment: what is ltealte? edit: ah makes sense now =)

Comment: Don't use _times_ as a verb. Use the grown-up version _multiply_.

Comment: One small note, there is also the option of choosing $0$ for each of the powers, so there are actually $(6+1)(2+1)(4+1)=105$ factors of $ab$ rather than $48$.

Comment: I would have said 4*2*3 distinct combinations

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to count the number of admissible choices for $$a=2^x\cdot 3^y\cdot 5^z\ ,\qquad x, \>y,\>z\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq0}\ .$$
The restrictions are 
$$x\leq6,\quad y\leq2,\quad z\leq4,\quad a\leq1000\ .$$

I propose a simple counting, according to the possible values of $z$:

Since $5^4=625$ the value $z=4$ enforces $x=y=0$. Gives ${\bf 1}$.

Since $5^3=125$ the value $z=3$ enforces $2^x\cdot 3^y\leq8$, hence $y=0$ and $0\leq x\leq3$, or $y=1$ and $0\leq x\leq1$. Gives ${\bf 6}$.

And so on: The value $z=2$ enforces $2^x\cdot 3^y\leq40$, $\ldots$